# How to close popup modal after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close popup modal after the checkbox is checked and then the button is clicked?

If checkbox is not checked then not to close modal. Checkbox and button placed inside modal. When I checking the checkbox and clicking the button modal is not closing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.one:checked').on('click' , '.close_model' , function(){

dialog('close');

});
    

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close_model btn btn-danger">button</button>

          <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the full code please.

Comment: Please don't spam tags, this has no relation to `php`

Comment: soory mistake plzz solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
            <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
            <div class="container">
                 <h2>Modal Example</h2>
                 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
                 <!-- Modal -->
                 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                             <!-- Modal content-->
                             <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="txt1" id="textbox1">
                                         <button type="button" class="close_model btn btn-danger">button</button>
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one" value="1">
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one" value="2">
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one" value="3">
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="ch" class="one" value="4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".close_model").on("click",function(){
                 if($('#textbox1').val() == 'true'){
                    $('.close').trigger('click');
                 }else{
                    alert('pls click on checkbox');
                 }
                 });
                 $('.one').change(function() {
                            if(this.checked) {
                                    $(this).prop("checked", 'true');
                            }
                            $('#textbox1').val(this.checked);
                    });
                 });
            </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not hide model

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$('.one:checked').on('click' , '.close_model' , function(){
$('#myModal').modal().hide();

});
    

})

Comment: you are greate dud

Answer (score 1):

change close button code like this

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close">Close</button>
```

and then add this JQuery code

```
$('.close').click(function(){

if ($('.one').is(':checked'))
{
 $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
}
```

})

here you go [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/18rxfby5/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there create a function and ad the function to button click event.

```
<button type="button" class="close_model btn btn-danger" onclick="CheckChecked();">button</button>

Function CheckChecked()
{
var x = document.getElementById("ch").checked;
    if (x)
{
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#selectItem").click(function(){

        var value = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

        $('#town').val(value);
        $("#myModal").modal('hide'); 
    });

<button type="button" id="selectItem" name="selectItem" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
```

The above code worked for me